# How to keep the merged Rmd file created during Merge and Knit

Tags: r, bookdown

`bookdown` merges all of the `Rmd` files into one, before knitting, but deletes this files at the end of the process.

I would like to examine the merged `Rmd` for debugging purposes. How can I tell `bookdown` not keep this intermediate file instead of erasing it?

**Update**

I found out about the `delete_merged_file` option in `_bookdown.yml`, but unfortunately, it seems to have no effect.

Comment: There are some comments on `delete_merged_file` [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/752).  That flag only sets whether to delete the merged markdown file when building; as things stand Bookdown always deletes the merged file after a successful build - see [this line in Bookdown source](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/67acec4/R/render.R#L134).