# Compile Bookdown to Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Is there any way to take a Bookdown project, and build it as **Markdown** instead of HTML or TeX?

I ask because I need to post-process the final Markdown output from Bookdown, in order to extract R and Python notebooks for download.

In more detail, I am using Bookdown to build a textbook that embeds notebooks to download, where the notebooks contain subsets of the code and text in the bookdown `.Rmd` files.  For example, a single chapter could contain more than one notebook.

In order to do this, I put start and end comment markers in the RMarkdown input text to identify the section that will be a notebook, and then post-process the generated Markdown files to extract the notebook section.  As in something like:

````
<!--- notebook: first_section.Rmd
-->

Some explanation, maybe using Bookdown extra markup such as @a_citation.

```{r}
a <- 1
a
```

<!--- end of notebook
-->

More markdown.

```{r}
# More code not in notebook.
b <- 2
```
````

Obviously I could use the input RMarkdown pages, but this would be ugly, because all the extended Bookdown markup such as citations, cross-references and so on, would appear in raw and ugly form in the generated notebook.  So I'd really like to be able to get the final output Markdown, after merging, resolving of citations and cross references.  Is there any way of doing that?

My question is similar to [this as-yet unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56031857/how-to-keep-the-merged-rmd-file-created-during-merge-and-knit), but adds my motivation for an official solution to this problem.

Comment: You could try setting the `clean` option to `FALSE` in the call to `render_book()` `bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', clean = FALSE)`,  (from: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/317)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I had tried `clean=FALSE`, but this leaves intermediate `.utf8.md` files in the source directory that are identical to the chapter `.md` files that I already get in the output directory from a knit / merge build. These files do have some markup resolved, but they do not have resolved `(ref:foo)` or citation references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of **bookdown** on CRAN, you can use the output format `bookdown::markdown_document2`, e.g.,

```
output: 
  bookdown::markdown_document2:
    base_format: rmarkdown::md_document
    variant: gfm
```